# In-ear bluetooth headset with good microphone

Tags: headset

I am looking for a headset which I can wear while cycling. I would prefer a bluetooth one, but a non-bluetooth headset might also be acceptable if the quality/price is really good.

It is important to me that the headset can deal with loud background (wind from driving; many people speaking when using public transportation).

I'm also using it when it rains. So [IPX4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Code#Second_digit:_Liquid_ingress_protection) would be good. But I guess most headsets which are not certified are also ok with this.

Price:

- < 30 EUR on amazon.de: Cool!
- [30 - 50) EUR: Acceptable
- [50 - 80] EUR: The quality would need to be really good
- more than 80 EUR: Let me know in the comments if you have one that you're really happy with, but that is more than I want to pay.

### Bad Examples

I've had a couple of headsets so far and I was not super happy with any of them. Two which I had for a longer time:

- **Samsung EG920**: The audio quality, microphone quality and the shape of the in-ear pieces was very good. It also was super cheap (< 5 EUR on Amazon). The problem is that they break super easily. In the last 6 months I had to buy 4 of them. Some broke and I have no idea why. Some broke because I got caught in the cable and pulled to hard on them (which was not super hard in the first place; after all, it was in my ear while I accidentially pulled it).
- **Mpow Flame Bluetooth**: I bought those because I hope that they don't break that easily. The ear-pieces are uncomfortable, the audio-quality is similar to the Samsung EG920. The main problem is that the microphone is in the ear-piece. So if I'm in a loud environment and I'm on the phone, it is super hard to understand my (or I have to shout really loud).